# Why am i getting ImportError: cannot import name 'PieChart' from 'openpyxl'

Tags: python, openpyxl

When I try to run this code in ViusalStudio I am getting this error.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import PieChart, Reference, Series, PieChart3D
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

data = [
    ['Flavor', 'Sold'],
    ['Vanilla', '1500'],
    ['Chocolate', '1600'],
    ['Strawberry', '600'],
    ['Pumpkin Spice', '950']
]

for rows in data:
    ws.append(rows)

chart = PieChart()
labels = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row= 2, max_row=5)
data = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row= 2, max_row=5)
chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(labels)
chart.title = 'Ice Cream By Flavor'

ws.add_chart(chart, 'C1')
wb.save('Pie1.xlsx')
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am using python 3.9.

Comment: What you’re doing wrong is (at least) not reading the documentation  https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/pie.html you’ll see PieChart isn’t in `openpyxl` it’s in `openpyxl.chart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below.

(read the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/pie.html))

```
from openpyxl.chart import (
    PieChart,
    Reference,
    Series, 
    PieChart3D
)
```